# Does this video portray Muslims being tortured?

Tags: video, malaysia, muslims, burma

[Video shared from this source](https://www.facebook.com/1257773027652526/videos/1258763344220161/) has the following caption.

[image: screenshot]

> هؤلاء مسلمو بورما يعذبون فقط لأنهم مسلمون ... من منكم يشعر بوجعهم ما عليه إلاّ محاولة نشر الفيديو على صفحات عالمية ربما تساعدهم ... و أدعوا لهم برطاجي جيم لصفحة [Video Live](https://www.facebook.com/1257773027652526/videos/1262840890479073/)
>
> These Muslims of Burma tortured just because they are Muslims... those of you who feel their face has only attempt to publish the video on global pages maybe you help them... and pray for them to share Jim Page [Video Live](https://www.facebook.com/1257773027652526/videos/1262840890479073/)

(*Facebook translation*)

I don't find the source to be reputable. With 3.1 M views and 13k shares, is this description legit? They're singing. It sounds like an anthem. Some of the comments indicate they're soldiers. That seems *far* more likely.

They're held in a cage submerged in the water with their head safely above  the water line.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

It seems as if the video comes from the [Malaysian GGK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grup_Gerak_Khas) -- their elite commandos. Here is [a similar video](https://youtu.be/WcZcoQgjS4A?t=29m8s) from [season one of the History Channel's *"Special Forces"*](http://www.historyasia.com/shows/special-forces)

> At 2 AM a group has been caught eating extra snails. Not sharing this bounty is against this rules. Recruit 2 is the leader of the pack. His whole team will be punished. They will wash the mud from their bodies and be tied to a wooden platform exposed to the elements.

Translated from the what the people in the video say,

> It is against the whole point of survival in the jungle. They will feel uncomfortable because they will be bitten by mosquitoes and sand flies and they can't scratch themselves or swat them away.

This doesn't rule out the hypothesis that they're Muslims being tortured. But it seems highly unlikely being they

- have similar hair cuts
- are in a similar cage by construction and size
- in similar water and environment
- are singing the [theme song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T8AE80kmhhg&feature=youtu.be) to [Darah Satria (1983)](https://ms.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darah_Satria) Thanks a ton to [/u/emptyNESS](https://www.reddit.com/r/malaysia/comments/63k5ca/i_believe_this_song_is_malaysian_what_song_is/dfusrfd/) for identifying the song. Clearly jingoistic you can find it in [lots of military stuff](https://youtu.be/z3etILXeRco).

[image: From the History Channel Documentary]

## Update

The exact video can be found be found on YouTube entitled [*Basic Komando*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nRVZ0uswXss). It was upload in Dec 2016 four months before the viral YouTube video by an account with [other GGK videos](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCKCSvfPpUx7QEw9WMO_Ocaw).

Comment: +1.  Given 60% of Malaysians are Muslim (and possibly more in particular  army units) while special forces selection worldwide is notoriously barbaric, these could indeed be Muslims being tortured.   But not from Burma, and not because they are Muslim.